# How to upload the entire folder with AJAX File Upload

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

Currently, I'm using AJAX File Upload to allow user to upload multiple files at same time and to provide drag & drop functionality. However, I need to allow them to upload the entire folder together with files. 
Is there anyway to get it done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The control you're in use, allow the multi-upload, but doesn't support your requested feature:
Quoted from [AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx)

> By taking advantage of the MaximumNumberOfFiles property, you can
>   limit the number of files which can be uploaded with the control. For
>   example, you can prevent a user from uploading more than 5 files.

Instead what you need its [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), this [tutorial](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/) can help you